# List of files under a directory in name order

Tags: linux, command-line, sorting

I wanted a list of files under a directory in name order to pass to an image viewer.

I am using `find $PHOTODIR -iname "*.jpg"`. Unfortunately this produces the images out of order.

On a USB key (formatted FAT32) I could understand files are processed in the order of directory entries, so I copied to a Ext4 drive, which I thought would produce files in name order, but there are still problems; I guess they are in inode order.

`ls` lists in order, but I need relative paths.

Can anyone suggest a suitable script?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If by "name order" you mean a simple alphabetical sorting, you could just `sort` the `find` results, which works fine as long as the files do not contain a newline in their name:

```
find "$PHOTODIR" -iname "*.jpg" | sort
```

If you want to pass these as arguments to an image viewer—or any other command—you need to pipe them to `xargs`. This works out of the box as long as there's no whitespace in the file names or paths.

If you want this to work with any file name or path, use the `-print0` argument to make `find`'s output delimited by NUL-characters, sort with `-z`, and use `xargs -0`:

```
find "$PHOTODIR" -iname "*.jpg" -print0 | sort -z | xargs -0 <command>
```